# How to reduce the time CURL takes to send some data?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL to send some data to an api , About 300 times using a for loop , It takes some time because the CURL is started and closed each time , I want to reduce the time it takes to loop , But keeps the same functionality.

Here is the code :

```
//$users = 300.
for ($i=0; $i < count($users); $i++){

    // some irrelevant code.

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,     "http://website.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"src": "'.$numbers_from[$i]['number_from'].'","dst": "'.$users[$i]['international_format'].'", "text": "'.$message.'"}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("XXXXX:YYYYYY")
    ));

    $message = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // some more code.

}
```

Comment: [`curl_multi_init()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: Not sure if this will help -but I set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS param to a low number when I need to kick off a file (that takes ages to process)

Comment: Move `curl_init()` and every `curl_setopt()` that isn't modified by the loop to before the loop, and move `curl_close()` to after the loop.

Comment: @SeanBright , It's the same url , but with different data sent to it.

Comment: @kevin that doesn't matter. If you use `curl_multi_*` you can run multiple requests simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

first some simple optimizations, stop counting $users on each iteration, function calls (eg, `count()`) are relatively expensive, a variable lookup is much faster. second, use pre-increment instead of post-increment on that $i increment, it's faster & use less cpu (in many compiled languages, the compilers auto-optmize this, but PHP doesn't), but better yet, use ForEach instead of for. it would also be faster to re-use the same curl session over and over instead of creating/deleting it every time. there is an async curl_multi interface, but it's slow and terribly cpu-hungry (no idea why, but it's been like that for years, something weird with PHP's implementation of it), i'd use multiple processes using curl_exec  over curl_multi.. try

```
$code = <<<'CODE'
<?php
    // some irrelevant code.

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,     "http://website.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"src": "'.$argv[1].'","dst": "'.$argv[2].'", "text": "'.$argv[3].'"}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("XXXXX:YYYYYY")
    ));
    $message = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $message;
    // some more code.  
CODE;
$jobFileh = tmpfile ();
$jobFile = stream_get_meta_data ( $jobFileh ) ['uri'];
file_put_contents($jobFile,$code);
// $users = 300.
$jobs = array ();
for($i = 0, $count = count ( $users ); $i < $count; ++ $i) {
    $jobs [] = '/usr/bin/php ' . escapeshellarg ( $jobFile ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg ( $numbers_from [$i] ['number_from'] ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg ( $users [$i] ['international_format'] ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg ( $message );
}
$ret = hhb_exec_multi1 ( $jobs, 100 );
var_dump ( $ret );
die ();
class hhb_exec_multi1_ret {
    public $cmd;
    public $ret;
    public $stdout;
    public $stderr;
    function __construct(array $attributes) {
        foreach ( $attributes as $name => $val ) {
            $this->$name = $val;
        }
    }
}
/**
 *
 * @param string[] $cmds
 * @param int $max_concurrent
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 * @return hhb_exec_multi1_ret[]
 */
function hhb_exec_multi1(array $cmds, int $max_concurrent = 10, $finished_callback = NULL): array {
    // TODO: more error checking, if proc_create fail, out of ram, tmpfile() fail, etc
    {
        // input validation
        if ($max_concurrent < 1) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException ( '$max_concurrent must be above 0... and less or equal to' . PHP_INT_MAX );
        }
        foreach ( $cmds as $tmp ) {
            if (! is_string ( $tmp )) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException ( '$cmds must be an array of strings!' );
            }
        }
    }
    $ret = array ();
    $running = array ();
    foreach ( $cmds as $key => $cmd ) {
        $current = array (
                'cmd' => $cmd,
                'ret' => - 1,
                'stdout' => tmpfile (),
                'stderr' => tmpfile (),
                'key' => $key 
        );
        $pipes = [ ];
        $descriptorspec = array (
                0 => array (
                        "pipe",
                        "rb" 
                ),
                1 => array (
                        "file",
                        stream_get_meta_data ( $current ['stdout'] ) ['uri'],
                        "wb" 
                ),
                2 => array (
                        "file",
                        stream_get_meta_data ( $current ['stderr'] ) ['uri'],
                        "wb" 
                )  // stderr is a file to write to
        );
        while ( count ( $running ) >= $max_concurrent ) {
            // echo ".";
            usleep ( 100 * 1000 );
            foreach ( $running as $runningkey => $check ) {
                $stat = proc_get_status ( $check ['proc'] );
                if ($stat ['running']) {
                    continue;
                }
                proc_close ( $check ['proc'] );
                $check ['ret'] = $stat ['exitcode'];
                $stdout = file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ( $check ['stdout'] ) ['uri'] );
                fclose ( $check ['stdout'] );
                $check ['stdout'] = $stdout;
                $stderr = file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ( $check ['stderr'] ) ['uri'] );
                fclose ( $check ['stderr'] );
                $check ['stderr'] = $stderr;
                $checkkey = $check ['key'];
                unset ( $check ['key'] );
                unset ( $check ['proc'] );
                $tmp = ($ret [$checkkey] = new hhb_exec_multi1_ret ( $check ));
                unset ( $running [$runningkey] );
                if (! empty ( $finished_callback )) {
                    $finished_callback ( $tmp );
                }
            }
        }
        $current ['proc'] = proc_open ( $cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes );
        fclose ( $pipes [0] ); // do it like this because we don't want the children to inherit our stdin, which is the default behaviour if [0] is not defined.
        $running [] = $current;
    }
    while ( count ( $running ) > 0 ) {
        // echo ",";
        usleep ( 100 * 1000 );
        foreach ( $running as $runningkey => $check ) {
            $stat = proc_get_status ( $check ['proc'] );
            if ($stat ['running']) {
                continue;
            }
            proc_close ( $check ['proc'] );
            $check ['ret'] = $stat ['exitcode'];
            $stdout = file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ( $check ['stdout'] ) ['uri'] );
            fclose ( $check ['stdout'] );
            $check ['stdout'] = $stdout;
            $stderr = file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ( $check ['stderr'] ) ['uri'] );
            fclose ( $check ['stderr'] );
            $check ['stderr'] = $stderr;
            $checkkey = $check ['key'];
            unset ( $check ['key'] );
            unset ( $check ['proc'] );
            $tmp = ($ret [$checkkey] = new hhb_exec_multi1_ret ( $check ));
            unset ( $running [$runningkey] );
            if (! empty ( $finished_callback )) {
                $finished_callback ( $tmp );
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

now it should do 100 requests simultaneously (configurable with the 2nd parameter to the hhb_exec_multi1 call), which would probably be muuuch faster.